# Flume's HttpSource: is the Jetty server multithread?

Tags: java, jetty, flume

I've been looking a bit to Flume's [HttpSource internals](https://github.com/apache/flume/blob/trunk/flume-ng-core/src/main/java/org/apache/flume/source/http/HTTPSource.java), trying yo figure out how the Jetty server is used.

I've seen a single element list of Connectors is used; this Connector will listen for incoming Http connections on configured Http host and port. Then a Context is created for the root path, and a HttpServlet is added to this Context containing the logic to be executed when a connection is received. Finally, the Jetty server is started.

```
Connector[] connectors = new Connector[1];

if (sslEnabled) {
    SslSocketConnector sslSocketConnector = new HTTPSourceSocketConnector(excludedProtocols);
    ...
    connectors[0] = sslSocketConnector;
} else {
    SelectChannelConnector connector = new SelectChannelConnector();
    ...
    connectors[0] = connector;
}

connectors[0].setHost(host);
connectors[0].setPort(port);
srv.setConnectors(connectors);

try {
    org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context root = new org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context(srv, "/", org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.SESSIONS);
    root.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new FlumeHTTPServlet()), "/");
    HTTPServerConstraintUtil.enforceConstraints(root);
    srv.start();
    ...
```

My question is, seen the above implementation: does such a Jetty server create a thread for each incoming Http connection? Or does a unique HttpServlet serve all the requests, one by one, sequentially?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

First of note: `org.mortbay.jetty` means you are using a **very old** version of Jetty.  Probably Jetty 5 or Jetty 6.  Those have been EOL (End of Life'd) way back in 2010 (and earlier).

Back in the Jetty 6 days, there was a ThreadPool that was used on-demand, and depending on your Connector type it would either result in a thread per connection (known as blocking connectors), or a thread per nio selection (in this case your 1 connections have many threads over the lifetime of the connection, but never more than 1 active per connection).

Starting with Jetty 8, and Servlet async, this threading model was refactored to favor async behavior of request processing more.

With Jetty 9, all blocking connectors were dropped in favor of supporting fully async processing of the request, its inputstreams, and its outputstreams.

The current model is for a ThreadPool of threads to be used, on demand, only when needed by a connection (this could be for processing of the request, or the response, or reading the request body content, or writing the response body content, or active websocket streaming, etc...)

This model is preferred for SPDY and HTTP/2 based support, where you have multiple requests per physical connection.  But know that in those models its quite possible to have multiple active threads per physical connection, depending on behavior of your servlets.

Also, the web application itself can choose to spin up more threads for its own processing, such as via the servlet async processing behaviors, or to initiate outgoing requests to other services, or to process other tasks that are unrelated to a specific request / response context.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Joakim, but the code I posted is not mine but the one implementing Apache Flume's `HTTPSource` class. That's why I woukd like to know if several connections are served in parallel with such a code.

Comment: "served in parallel" is a vague description.  it can mean many different things depending on context.  but if you are concerned about threading with Flume, then assume the worst case scenario (1 thread per connection + 1 thread per request/response pair within that connection) just because the implementation is so old.